# Carthage: Error installing Carthage "An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step"

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, carthage

I'm trying to install Carthage using brew but I'm getting this errors:

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
```

I tried this command:

`brew link carthage`

But I'm getting this error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/carthage/0.30.1... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
```

Any of you knows how can fix this or a work around this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same error. I was able to link Carthage after I created those folders with:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework
```

Then I had to change owner of CarthageKit.framework to myself:

```
sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework
```

I ran

```
brew link carthage
```

again and it worked.

Comment: you should add also :
sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/Frameworks/
in order to use brew upgrade carthage
to be able to upgrade carthage.